# Replacing WKT with WKB in PostGIS query & Shapely

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas, shapely, well-known-binary

I am extracting a geometry (type `geometry(Geometry,4326)`) from a PostGIS database.  I managed to plot them from a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame using the following code :

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id, ST_asText(wkb_geometry) FROM mydb")

rows=[]
for id, geom in cursor:
    data = {'id': id, 'geometry': shapely.wkt.loads(geom)}
    rows.append(data)

geopandas.GeoDataFrame(rows,crs='epsg:4326').plot()
```

Figuring WKB would be more efficient than WKT, I was expecting querying with `ST_Binary()/ST_AsEWKB()/ST_AsTWKB()` and loading with `shapely.wkb.loads(geom)` to be equivalent to the above, but it throws a

> TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of memoryview instance

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the `psycopg2` database driver returns blob values as [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) objects.

You can convert them into `bytes` objects with `bytes(geom)` or `geom.tobytes()`.

---

[This post on the psycpg mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2Bmi_8Zy50LYof%3DFfO9qybeQJfoLPpUXCand8CBvapS%3DXoCkGg%40mail.gmail.com) shows how to change the returned type of blobs by registering a new type:

```
def bytea2bytes(value, cur):
    m = psycopg2.BINARY(value, cur)
    if m is not None:
        return m.tobytes()

BYTEA2BYTES = psycopg2.extensions.new_type(
    psycopg2.BINARY.values, 'BYTEA2BYTES', bytea2bytes)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(BYTEA2BYTES)

cur.execute("select 'abcdef'::bytea")
cur.fetchone()[0]    # returns b'abcdef'
```